# The best way to have an addEventListener on IE < 9

Tags: javascript

element.addEventListener is not supported on IE < 9.

What is the best way for having a similar function?

Comment: Use [jQuery!](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has `attachEvent`

```
if (el.addEventListener){  
  el.addEventListener('click', callback, false);   
} else if (el.attachEvent){  
  el.attachEvent('onclick', callback);  
}
```

More at [MDN: Legacy Internet Explorer and attachEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Legacy_Internet_Explorer_and_attachEvent)

Comment: Be careful doing this though: every browser has slightly different behaviours for events – particularly IE. Consider using jQuery or similar (as suggested by @archil) which helps unify browser event models.